# SciChart: ColumnChart - DataSeries.Append

Tags: scichart

A potential problem I noticed in SciChart for WPF

- take the standard example for ColumnChart from  SDK (2D Charts - Column Chart)
- build and run; the result is as below:
  [image]
- make the following code changes (see (1) and (2))

  ```
  private void ColumnChartExampleViewOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

      var dataSeries = new XyDataSeries<double, double> {SeriesName = "Histogram"};

      var yValues = new double[] { 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.1, 1.5, 2.4, 4.6, 8.1, 11.7, 14.4, 16.0, 13.7, 10.1, 6.4, 3.5, 2.5, 1.4, 0.4, 0.1};

      using (this.sciChart.SuspendUpdates())
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < yValues.Length; i++)
          {
              // DataSeries for appending data
              dataSeries.Append(i, yValues[i]);
          }

          this.columnSeries.DataSeries = dataSeries;
          this.columnSeries.DataSeries.AcceptsUnsortedData = true; //(1)
      }

      dataSeries.Append(0, 1); //(2)
      this.sciChart.ZoomExtents();
  }
  ```
- and here is the result:
  [image]

I.e. if I use Append method for the X val which already exists - the UI bars are changing to the lines. 
I do not know if it is expected behavior or not but for my case I'm updating the Histogram on fly and quite often same X value is having new Y value(s).
As a result - the UI behavior confuses... 
I found workaround for my case (I'm using the Update method since X and index is the same for my case) so this is just a notice.

I'm not sure will you change the behavior or not - just sharing my experience for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciChart's column series automatically calculates the width of the data-points based on the columns you have available.

If you have columns 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ...then add a new column at position 0, this calculation goes haywire.

Ways of avoiding this side-effect are:

- Update items rather than append new columns with overlapping values
- Override column width calculation using the properties `FastColumnRenderableSeries.UseUniformWidth` and `FastColumnRenderableSeries.DataPointWidth`
- (Advanced) Override column width calculation by overriding [GetDataPointWidth()](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Visuals.RenderableSeries.BaseRenderableSeries~GetDatapointWidth.html) method.

Find out more how the Column series works at the [SciChart WPF Documentation page](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/The%20Column%20Series%20Type.html).